# Query slowed to a crawl when joined on something besides id number

Tags: mysql, sql

My query went from pretty fast, to all out slow when I changed it from joining with ID number, to Item Number.   Here's what I have:

```
SELECT DISTINCT n.id,n.shortdesc,n.cost,o.cost as oldcost, n.itemnum,     
n.segment2 as category, 
IF(n.cost != o.cost, 1, 0) AS 'diff'
FROM Ind_new n
INNER JOIN Ind o ON o.suppliernum = n.suppliernum  
LIMIT 1000
```

I'm comparing two tables with varying products.  The id number of course changes which throws my query all over the place so I tried to compare by item number.  The item number can be from 3 to 10 characters, but are the same in both tables.  What is it that would have slowed my query down so drastically?

Comment: What indexes do you have on your tables?

Comment: The only field that is indexed is the "itemnum" field on both tables.  The fieldtype is varchar(20).  I have a feeling the varchar is partly what's slowing it down because the id field is an int and running just fine.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't keep the id numbers related? What did you mean by "of course changes"?

Comment: It starts as an excel file from our supplier and then gets imported in to the db, They add products, remove products etc..

Comment: That doesn't sound like a candidate key (i.e. id) then

Answer (score 0):

String fields are generally abysmal for relational operations; and an index can only help that so much. Make sure both VARCHAR fields have the same NULL/NOT NULL definition (if possible); I recently encountered a similar problem in my work and was surprised by how much of a difference it made.